# Using Regular Expressions to iterate through a python dictionary created from a tab delimited table

Tags: python

I have the following table (tab delimited) for students. The name, class, grade in August, then grade in September provided.

```
1   Tom Bever   101 20,6    21,3
2   John Hein   102 23,7    22,4
3   Melissa Andrew  401 24,1    25,3
```

I converted it into python dictionary using this code:

```
myfile = open ("students.txt", "r")
d = { }
for line in myfile:
    x = line.strip().split("\t")
    key, values = x[1], x[2:]
    d.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)
print(d)
```

Now, I need to use regular expressions to compute

1. The name of the student with the lowest grade
2. The name of the student(s) with an increase
3. order them according to the highest grades they got in September

So, how can I iterate through the dictionary using RE to answer these questions?

Comment: But how you want to do that, by average or minimum value, or what?

Comment: by minimum or maximum values.

Comment: How do you determine "lowest grades"? Do you take the average of two grades per student?

Comment: Please revise questions 2 and 3 as they are not clear. Do you need the data in dictionary? I guess it could be more efficiently if you just start with regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those three results like:

#### Code:

```
with open("students.txt", "r") as f:
    d = {y[1]: list(map(float, y[2:])) for y in (
        x.strip().split("\t") for x in f)}
print(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: min(x[1][1:3]))[0][0])
print([k for k, v in d.items() if v[1] < v[2]])
print([k for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][2])])
```

#### Results:

```
Tom Bever
['Tom Bever', 'Melissa Andrew']
['Melissa Andrew', 'John Hein', 'Tom Bever']
```